# Angular 9 refresh component after callback received on service

Tags: angular, typescript, listener, angular-ng-if, ngzone

I'm new in Angular and also a bit lost. I'm trying to implement the google sign on in an angular app but i cannot make it work. The idea is to show the sign in button and once the user has completed it, refresh the component showing his data and photo.

I managed to init the gApi and subscribe to login events by using their methods, but i don't know how to make the component to reload after the corresponding listener is called. I have been trying using subject.AsObservable() -> subscription to try to deal with this, and even if i know the callback is called, the component is not updated.

A friend told me to use EventEmmitter to deal with this, but as the callback is inside a service and i don't need to reload the parent, i'm not sure if this is will work.

Also i'm reading about ngZones which could make the trick (but i'm not sure if this a kind of anti-pattern). I write here the code i have now.

header.html

```html
<div *ngIf="this.loggedIn else showLogin">
    <p>{{this.getBasicProfile().getName()}}</p>
    <p>{{this.getBasicProfile().getEmail()}}</p>
    <img [src]="this.getBasicProfile().getImageUrl()"/>
</div>

<ng-template #showLogin>
    {{this.loggedIn}}
    <div class="g-signin2"></div>
</ng-template>
```

header.ts

```js
    import { Component, OnInit, OnDestroy } from '@angular/core';
    import { GoogleService } from '../google.service'
    import { Subscription } from 'rxjs';

    @Component({
      selector: 'app-header',
      templateUrl: './header.component.html',
      styleUrls: ['./header.component.sass']
    })

    export class HeaderComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
      constructor(protected google : GoogleService) { 

      }

      loggedIn: boolean = false;
      subscription : Subscription;

      getBasicProfile() {
          return this.google.getUserProfile();
      }

      ngOnInit(): void {
        this.subscription = this.google.loggedIn$.subscribe(loggedIn => {
          this.loggedIn = loggedIn;
        });

        this.google.init().then(() => {
          this.google.listenUserChanges();
        });
      }

      ngOnDestroy(): void {
        this.subscription.unsubscribe();
      }
    }
```

google.service.ts

```js
    import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
    import { BehaviorSubject, Subscriber } from 'rxjs';

    declare const gapi: any;

    @Injectable({
      providedIn: 'root'
    })

    export class GoogleService {
      private loggedIn: BehaviorSubject<boolean> = new BehaviorSubject<boolean>(false);

      auth: any;
      profile: any;
      loggedIn$ = this.loggedIn.asObservable();

      public init(): Promise<boolean> {
        let doInit = new Promise<boolean>((resolve, reject) => {

          gapi.load('auth2', () => {
            gapi.auth2.init({
              client_id: "XXXXXX.apps.googleusercontent.com",
              cookiepolicy: 'single_host_origin',
            }).then(auth => {
              this.auth = auth;
              resolve();
            });
          });

        });

        return doInit;
      }

      public listenUserChanges(): void {
        if (!this.isLoggedIn()) {
          this.auth.isSignedIn.listen(() => {
            this.getUserProfile()
          });
          this.auth.currentUser.listen(() => {
            this.getUserProfile()
          });
        }
      }

      public isLoggedIn(): boolean {
        if (this.auth) {
          let isLoggedIn = this.auth.isSignedIn.get();
          this.loggedIn.next(isLoggedIn);
          return isLoggedIn;
        }

        return false;
      }

      public getUserProfile(): any {
        if (this.auth && this.isLoggedIn()) {
          this.profile = this.auth.currentUser.get().getBasicProfile();
          return this.profile;
        }

        return null;
      }

      constructor() {
        this.auth = null;
      }
    }
```

any suggestion will be more than welcomed.

thanks!!

Comment: Is this  this.google.loggedIn$ and your google login process working correctly?

Comment: yes, i had put breakpoints in the browser and i see how the this.loggedIn in the component gets updated, but the *ngIf in the html is not re-evaluated afterwards

Comment: A possible reason for a component not being rendered when smth changed is that it uses OnPush or some of its parents in the components tree uses OnPush. If that's the case, you would need to call changeDetectorRef.markForCheck() each time you update properties of your components that particupate in rendering.

But frankly, a lot is wrong in the original code. isLoggedIn() check performs a side effect - emits a new value to the subject. It means a new value is gonna be emitted every time a component renders. I would suggest starting with some solid refactoring of GoogleService

Comment: Yes, probably this is not the best way to do this, but that's the result of my iteration... I tried to put everything in the component, but once the callbacks from google arrived, this object was undefined, so i moved everything to the service, but now the component doesn't get updated. I'll try what you say, but as you suggest it seems it's better to think a bit more about it and change the design completely... I'll try to read a bit more and improve it. Anyway i'd like to know how i could achieve this.... thanks!

Comment: about what @amakhrov said, i have just done a refactor puting the listeners inside the component to try to avoid updating many things around everytime i check if i'm logged in. I guess in this case to make things work i still need to put it in angular zone (as this comes from a js callback) to make the component refresh when the value changes, right?

Comment: You only need to explicitly run smth in ngZone if the original callback was for whatever reason outside the zone. It can generally happen in 2 cases: (1) You manually executed smth outside zone (`ngZone.runOutsideAngular()`). (2) The original async call was triggered by something not patched with Zone (I can easily imagine google sdk doing smth very custom here). In both cases what you would need to do `ngZone.run(yourCallback)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @amakhrov suggested using ngZone.run() i was able to update the component when finishing the sign on with google API. Also the idea of doing the refactor to avoid unecessary updates using Subscription model was interesting, Thanks!